# Difference between intel-driver and GPU

Tags: kernel, drivers, hardware, intel

I have a i7-6700 HQ
and therefore a HD Graphics **530** integrated

However I'm confused about "what-is-what" in my system since my kernel is using a driver called **i915**. Is this the "main" driver for intel-CPUs on linux and is there a list with a lineup of drivers and supported chipsets?

Comment: Yes, that's the main driver, see [Why is the Intel HD Graphics driver called i915?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224240)