# Why is the Mesa OpenGL driver for Intel chips called i965?

Tags: history, i915, mesa

As I understand, most Intel GPUs are supported on Linux by two different components : i965 (the Mesa/OpenGL part, supporting all recent Intel GPUs) and i915 (kernel part, similarly supporting all recent Intel GPUs).

The relationship between the two is not very clearly explained anywhere I found, especially now that names like iHD (for VAAPI), or Iris (newer chips) are mixed in, but essentially I understand that i965 uses features exposed from the kernel by i915 (syscalls/ioctls?) to expose the OpenGL API to applications.

While [Why is the Intel HD Graphics driver called i915?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224240/why-is-the-intel-hd-graphics-driver-called-i915) answers the question about the kernel part, why use a similar yet different product name for the Mesa component that supports all Intel GPUs anyway? Is there a reason behind it, or just history?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mesa i965 driver doesn’t support all Intel GPUs. There are two Mesa drivers corresponding to the i915 kernel driver: the i965 driver, which supports GPUs since Broadwater (aka [965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Core_2_chipsets)), and the i915 driver, which supports older GPUs since Grantsdale (aka [915](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Pentium_4/Pentium_D/Pentium_EE_chipsets)).

The i965 driver was contributed by Tungsten Graphics in [Mesa 6.5.1](https://docs.mesa3d.org/relnotes/6.5.1.html).

Comment: That's the info I needed, thank you so much. The i915 Mesa driver seems very rarely mentioned nowadays in documentation (with good reason, it's old), and I was curious about the history ;)